# Conversion from String to Byte in java

Tags: java

I am converting a Byte data to String and this string back to byte.However when i try to convert this string back to byte i am unable to retrieve the byte data back.I know i am doing something very silly some were.Can somebody please let me know what is the error?Following is my code in java

```
Log.e("byte data",""+byte_data[3]);  //70
Log.e("data in string",""+Integer.toBinaryString(byte_data[3]));  //1000110
String data=Integer.toBinaryString(byte_song[3]);
Log.e("byte data",""+data.getBytes());
```

However  dat.getBytes() returns  [B@414eaa48 however it should have returned me 70.

Comment: Hint: `dat.getBytes`, as its name suggests, returns an _array_.

Comment: Even after reading your code, I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  Does the String contain binary number you can turn into a byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dat.getBytes()` provides an array of bytes , which is itself an object in java. Whenever you try to print out that object or call `toString()` , it calls the `toString()` method of `java.lang.Object` class. In `java.lang.Object` class `toString()` is defined in following way:

```
public String  toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

That's why you are getting such output. To achieve what you want
 
`Log.e("byte data",""+dat.getBytes());` should be changed to 
`Log.e("byte data",""+java.util.Arrays.toString(dat.getBytes()));`
**UPDATE**
To get `70` back you should use:
`Log.e("byte data",""+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(byte_data[3]),10));`
**OR**
`Log.e("byte data",""+Integer.parseInt(data,2));` 
To know how it worked Look at here **[Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)**

Comment: ,I would want the output to be back as 70(in this case).What is the change i need to make?

Comment: Hey Vishal thanks for Your reply and time,However i want to get back the byte(70) using the dat variable(String data ) not from byte_data[3].As u mentioned Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(byte_data[3]),10);

Answer (score 2):

[`getBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) returns a `byte` array, and the `toString` methods of arrays do not display their contents (which can be annoying at times). Try [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29) to show the contents of arrays instead. Note that for an object `x`, `"" + x` is equivalent to `x.toString()`.